# RaspBMC doesn't let terminal stay open

Tags: raspbmc

I am having issues staying in the terminal once I have exited RaspBMC. I exit RaspBMC, the terminal stays open just long enough for me to enter raspberrypi login, but then the media centre starts to reboot (I get the RaspBMC logo then it opens the media centre). How do I stop it jumping out of the terminal?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of exiting XBMC with the "off" button, you can switch to another virtual terminal by hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F2</kbd> on your keyboard. From there, you should be able to enter the default username (`pi`) and password (`raspberry`).

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately Ctrl+Alt+F2 (or any other F button) doesn't seem to do anything, don't know if it's my keyboard or something else.